# Screen independent way to detect clicks outside a widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm looking for a screen independent way to detect clicks outside a widget.

Normally to detect clicks outside a widget I would need to wrap my screen around a `GestureDetector` with `behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque` (or something like that).

Example:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () => handleClickOutside(),
      child: Container(
        child: MyWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

The problem is that if I want to use this widget anywhere, I would have to wrap every screen...

So my question is, is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do without the mandatory screen wrap?

Comment: you should use `GestureDetector` inside `MyWidget` then

Comment: @pskink I don't see how that helps. I want to detect clicks outside `MyWidget`, I don't see how having `GestureDetector` inside `MyWidget` would help in any way.

Comment: indeed, I got you wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the amount of boiler plate code by creating you own widget that collects all the stuff you need on every page:

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  MyPage({super.key, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: handleClickOutside,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }

  void handleClickOutside() {
    // here is where you handle the click outside any widget
  }
}
```

Note that you `Container` in you sample is not necessary.

Note the use of a method tear-off for the `onTap` parameter

Comment: I'll try that, but in the context of what I have to do, it means going into multiple repos and adding `MyPage` everywhere.

For context, the app I'm working on for this company is spread across multiple repositories that act as single pages each (don't know why they did that).
I was hoping that there was a scenario in which I would be able to do what I need to without having to change all these repos, but alas, here we are.